# marquee issue in android 4.1.1 custom notification

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

Hi i have my custom notification in my app, works perfect in android 2.2 2.3 4.0 but not in 4.1.1 jelly bean i tried but i cant get marquee working in my custom notification heres my code .xml:

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/notification_title"
        style="@style/NotificationTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >

            <requestFocus />
        </TextView>

        <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/notification_text"
        style="@style/NotificationText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/notification_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="15sp" >
        </TextView>
```

my notification code:

```
            int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
            int icon = R.drawable.notificacion;
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            CharSequence tickerText = "Reproduciendo...";

            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText,
                    when);


            RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, txtMetaTitle.getText().toString());
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, txtMetaUrl.getText().toString());
            notification.contentView = contentView;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(AACPlayerActivity.this, Principal.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AACPlayerActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }
```

my app works good but the marquee doesnt starts dont know why in 4.1.1? what can i do to fix this issue?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: building notifications in `Notification` is deprecated in favor of using the `Builder` subclass. Also, to get compatibility across platforms you should consider using `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`. You should be able to use the same `RemoteViews`; try switching to the new way and see what happens.

Comment: can give me some example? i need to import something that lib?